# Software for Typing Scanscion

Tags: software, poetry

Is there software specially designed for typing scanscion symbols synced with the words below them?

In Word for example, inserting a 2 x 1  matrix , and increasing the column incrementally for each syllable of a line, allows for  stressed, breve, or partial stress symbols to be typed in the 1st row, and words in the 2nd, with vertical lines for feet division as seen below:

[image]

The problem with this method however is that the act of adding or deleting columns is tedious, as it requires a three click process just to add or delete a single column.  So in efforts to save time one would need to create a template (2 x n) matrix (where n is the amount of syllables) and paste it every line.

So I'm wondering if there is any software better purposed for scanscion than my makeshift method.

Comment: Hi, @TomDot Com. Welcome to Writing SE. Does this answer your question? [Scansion tool for checking my meter](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43000/scansion-tool-for-checking-my-meter)

Comment: @roifedh Hi. Not quite. I'm looking for software that makes scanscion easier to produce on a computer, rather than writing it out and uploading. Although thanks for the resource to improve my abilities at scanscion, it's the ability to digitally display scanscion symbols in a manner similar to writing it down, that I really desire.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck in your search. I'm not sure this question is very relevant to the Writing SE community. Please do post a comment here letting us know if you find what you're looking for.